# angular 7 in dashboard.component.ts

Tags: angular7

src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts:9:14
9 export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
'DashboardComponent' is declared here.

Error: src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts:11:23 - error NG2003: No suitable injection token for parameter 'studentService' of class 'DashboardComponent'.
Consider using the @Inject decorator to specify an injection token.

11   constructor(private studentService:StudentService) { }
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts:11:38
11   constructor(private studentService:StudentService) { }
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
This type does not have a value, so it cannot be used as injection token.

Error: src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts0m:3:32 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../student.service' or its corresponding type declarations.

3 import { StudentService } from '../student.service';
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 0):

In the module that this component is imported in, try adding the CommonModule

```
imports: [CommonModule],
```

This might be one of the issues.